# Unable to import header via EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am actually in the learning phase of Node JS and Express. I am making a small portfolio app for myself using the above. I want to make my header and footer reusable across my code and upon doing some research, I found out that EJS is the best option for doing so. But I am stuck as I cannot get the desired output.

**My HTML page** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sambhav Dave | Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <%- include('partials/header') %>
        <br><br>
        <div class="card text-center">

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Quote of the day !</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Everything in moderation, even moderation.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                <i>By Mark Twain</i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <hr>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <br />
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <h2>Visitor Count</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-people-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M7 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 5-4 5 3 5 4-1 1-1 1H7zm4-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z" />
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M5.216 14A2.238 2.238 0 0 1 5 13c0-1.355.68-2.75 1.936-3.72A6.325 6.325 0 0 0 5 9c-4 0-5 3-5 4s1 1 1 1h4.216z" />
                            <path d="M4.5 8a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5z" />
                        </svg>
                        <i class="bi bi-people-fill"></i>
                        <h2 class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="1700" data-speed="1500"></h2>
                        <p class="count-text ">Vistor Count comes here (put some style here)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My index.js (entry point for nodejs)** :

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

const port = 8080;

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: './src/views' })
});

app.get('/secret', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('admin.html', { root: './src/views' })
});

app.get('/aboutme', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('aboutme.html', { root: './src/views' })
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
});
```

**My header.ejs** :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sambhav's Portfolio</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hobby Projects</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blogs</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">My Photography</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**The output I am getting** :

[image]

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sendFile` method just sends a file.

If you want to render a view using the view engine you selected you need to use the `render` method.